# Enemies not spawning in

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame
import constants
import levels
import random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from player import Player

BADDIEMINSIZE = 45
BADDIEMAXSIZE = 55
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 13
BADDIEMINSPEED = 1
BADDIEMAXSPEED = 3
TEXTCOLOR = (255, 255, 255)

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    for b in baddies:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def main():
    """ Main Program """
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mp3')

    # set up sounds
    smalljump = pygame.mixer.Sound('small_jump.ogg')
    startmenu = pygame.mixer.Sound('startmenu.ogg')

    # set up fonts
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

    #set up images
    baddieImage = pygame.image.load('baddie.png')

    # Set the height and width of the screen
    size = [constants.SCREEN_WIDTH, constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("OVER 9000 WHEN HE CHECK THE SCOUTER")

    # Create the player
    player = Player()

    # Create all the levels
    level_list = []
    level_list.append(levels.Level_01(player))

    # Set the current level
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level
    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)

    #Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False
    # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # show the "Start" screen
    drawText('THE INTERNET OF THINGS', font, screen, (constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 3) - 40, (constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    drawText('Press a key to start.........', font, screen, (constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 3), (constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) + 100)
    startmenu.play()
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    #GAME LOOP
    score = 0

    startmenu.stop()
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

    while not done:
        baddieAddCounter = 0
        baddies = []
        score += 1
        fact = ""

        baddieAddCounter += 1
        if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
            baddieAddCounter = 0
            baddieSize = random.randint(BADDIEMINSIZE, BADDIEMAXSIZE)
            newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                        'speed': random.randint(BADDIEMINSPEED, BADDIEMAXSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                        }
            baddies.append(newBaddie)

        #GIVES PLAYER A NEW FACT EVERYTIME THEY REACH THE TARGET SCORE
        if score < 400:
           fact = 'NOTHING'

        elif score > 400 and score <= 799:
           fact = 'Physical objects having network connectivity'

        elif score > 800 and score <= 1100:
           fact = '1982 - First inter-connected appliance: Coke machine'


        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
        drawText('Fact: %s' % (fact), font, screen, 10, 40)
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():     
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    smalljump.play()
                    player.jump()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    smalljump.play()
                    player.jump()
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    terminate()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                   player.stop()


        # Move the baddies down.
        for b in baddies:
            b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])

        # Draw each baddie
        for b in baddies:
            screen.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in baddies[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOW_HEIGHT:
                baddies.remove(b)
        pygame.display.update()

        pygame.display.update()                          
        active_sprite_list.update()
        current_level.update()

        #WHEN PLAYER GOES RIGHT, SHIFT WORLD LEFT
        if player.rect.right >= 500:
            diff = player.rect.right - 500
            player.rect.right = 500
            current_level.shift_world(-diff)

        #WHEN PLAYER FOES LEFT, SHIFT WORLD RIGHT
        if player.rect.left <= 120:
            diff = 120 - player.rect.left
            player.rect.left = 120
            current_level.shift_world(diff)

        # RESTRICTS PLAYER FROM GOING TO FAR TO THE RIGHT
        current_position = player.rect.x + current_level.world_shift
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            player.rect.x = 120  

        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For some reason my enemies (baddies) are not spawning in, i got all the baddie code from another program called "dodger" so i don't know why it's not working. It works when i tried it in dodger obviously but when i put it in my code nothing happens. My code still runs but when you're playing no baddies will fall from the sky like it's supposed to. There are other modules for this code but i didn't add them.

Comment: what a mess. use `pygame.dispkay.update()` only once in loop.

Comment: what is doing `current_level.draw()` ? Is it drawing background ? Then this background hides your baddies.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code, but your current problem is that you create a new list of baddies every iteration of your main loop:

```
...
while not done:
    baddieAddCounter = 0
    baddies = []
    score += 1
    fact = ""
    ...
```

You should move `baddies = []` outside the `while` loop.

---

You already seem to use sprites and groups, so I don't know why do you use dicts for your baddies instead of sprites.